# FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm using postgresql 12 with pgadmin4 on ubuntu 20.04. I'm having an issue with creating a new server. I don't remember specifying any password during installation but now i don't know what the password is and whatever i try to put it just gives a password error saying authentication failed. [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV1g7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a user and password with (don't miss the semicolon):

```
CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'your password';
```

After this, try authenticating your USER in pgAdmin4

For more refer to this link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the password or connect to PostgreSQL without password by modifying `pgconf.hba` file and then try to connect.

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how should I express my thanks to @1337.ishaan and @a_horse_with_no_name without which I couldn't have logged into Postgres through pgadmin4. But a small edit to that:

1. First we have to get inside postgres through using

   `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`
2. Enter password for user postgres

Now the terminal will be like this:

```
postgres=#
```

3. Now enter the given line after postgres=#
   `CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'your password';`
   (put your password inside quotes('') and don't forget semicolon(;)